# Hide ImageView in Listview from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

The Listview on the main activity is public static which is accessible to all activities. Now my question is when the second activity shows I want to hide the nth ImageView in the ListView in the main activity. Here's my code:

**(Activity 1) MainActivity onCreate()**

```
    public static ListView lvmsgs;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    lvmsgs= this.getListView();
    lvmsgs.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {;
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageThread.class);
            i.putExtra("contactNum", sortedcontactnum.get(position));
            i.putExtra("contactName", sortedcontactname.get(position));
            i.putExtra("pos", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    }
```

**(Activity 2) MessageThread.java onCreate()**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListView lvinlist= (ListView) findViewById(id.msgList);
    ImageView greenbtn= (ImageView) lvinlist.getItemAtPosition(extras.getInt("pos"));
    greenbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

It crashes my app. If anybody could help me.

Comment: post your adapter code. Also the log of error

Comment: You have to use context of that activity instead of current activity

Comment: can you clarify whether above thread runs in MainActivity or SecondActivity?

Comment: There's no problem with my adapter. The line greenbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  crashes my app. @AnandSavjani how can I get the context of the first activity?

Comment: A few comments: 1. The `ListView` will be constructed in the context of your `MainActivity` - which is a memory leak when you move to the second `Activity`. You should avoid this. 2. Post your logcat so we can see the error. Almost certainly it is a problem on this line `ListView lvinlist= (ListView) findViewById(id.msgList);` because the id of the `ListView` is on the MainActivity, and you are now in `MessageThread` activity, which would throw a NPE on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you...

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ListView lvinlist= (ListView) findViewById(id.msgList);
ImageView greenbtn= (ImageView) lvinlist.getItemAtPosition(extras.getInt("pos"));
greenbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
MainActivty.lvmsgs.getChildAt(nthChild).setVisibility(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way around, meaning let MainActivity be responsible for hiding the image, not the MessageThread.

One problem with the way you have it is that Android can kill MainActivity pretty much any time it isn't visible, including when it's covered by MessageThread.  So, your way might work most of the time time but it's not reliable.

Instead, you can set a global flag or you can use some sort of messaging communications.  Then, when MainActivity is restored, check the flag or whatever and do the work of hiding the image.

For example, you can subclass the Application class to store a global variable.  You can't rely on access to MainActivity but you can rely on Application.  Then, review the life cycle docs and choose a good point to do the hiding work.  Probably in onResume().

Comment: It works for me  if I let MainActivity handle the hiding of the image. But the image hides before the second activity shows. What I want to achieve is when I click on the listview item, the second activity shows then the image on that clicked listview item hides.

Comment: So your second activity doesn't completely cover MainActivity?  In that case, you should be safe that MainActivity won't be destroyed.  You might do a post() or a postDelayed() in second activity's onCreate().  That will cause the second activity to render before it tries to hide the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that extends `Application` and can refer to your `Activity` `context` from other `Activity`. I am posting some code for your reference.

**AppController**- our Application class

```
public class AppController extends Application {

ActionChooserActivity activity;

private static AppController instance;

public static AppController getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
}

public void setCurrentActivity(ActionChooserActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public ActionChooserActivity getCurrentActivity() {
    return activity;
}
```

}

Then in your `MainActivity` do something like this:

`AppController appController;`

then in your `onCreate()` of `MainActivity` initialize `AppController` object like this

`appController = (AppController) getApplication();
 appController.setCurrentActivity(this);`

Then in your `Activity` containing `ListView` do something like this:

`AppController appController;`

in `onCreate()`

`appController = (AppController) getApplication();`

and on button click call a method of your `MainActivity`

`appController.getCurrentActivity().showToast();`

See here `showToast()` is a dummy method created in 'MainActivity' class so create one such method and hide your `ImageView` there.

And yes make sure you declare 'AppController' in the application tag in `Android Manifest` file like below:

`android:name="your.package.name.AppController"`

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed. I have my code on my second activity to:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ImageView greenBtn= (ImageView) MainActivity.lvmsgs.getChildAt(extras.getInt("pos")).findViewById(R.id.greenButton);
          greenBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Thank everyone.